# Swift - How to remove swipe gesture from scene when moving to another one?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, uigesturerecognizer

So my game uses swipe gestures, in my didMoveToView() function I have these gestures initialized:

```
            let swipeRight = UISwipeGestureRecognizer()
            swipeRight.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Right
            self.view?.addGestureRecognizer(swipeRight)

            let swipeLeft = UISwipeGestureRecognizer()
            swipeLeft.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Left
            self.view?.addGestureRecognizer(swipeLeft)

            let swipeUp = UISwipeGestureRecognizer()
            swipeUp.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Up
            self.view?.addGestureRecognizer(swipeUp)

            let swipeDown = UISwipeGestureRecognizer()
            swipeDown.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Down
            self.view?.addGestureRecognizer(swipeDown)
```

Problem is when I move to my GameOver scene, and I swipe, it crashes my app. I noticed someone had posted something similar and got this as an answer

```
override func willMoveFromView(view: SKView) {
   for recognizer in self.view.gestureRecognizers! {
       self.view.removeGestureRecognizer(recognizer)
   }
}
```

Still not quite sure how to implement this and/or remove the gestures from the scene before switching to game over. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The following removes all swipe gesture recognizers from the view:

```
override func willMoveFromView(view: SKView) {
    if let gestures = view.gestureRecognizers {
        for gesture in gestures {
           if let recognizer = gesture as? UISwipeGestureRecognizer {
                view.removeGestureRecognizer(recognizer)
           }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Its not working for me!!!. Every time view.gestureRecognizers gives nil.

Comment: @PintuRajput are you sure that you added the gesture to the SKView? When you add a gesture to a view, the gesture is automatically added to view's `gestureRecognizers` property, an array. Even if you removed all gestures, `gestureRecognizers` will reference an empty array (not nil).

Answer (score 0):

You are removing all kind of gesture, try this:

```
if([recognizer isKindOfClass:[UISwipeGestureRecognizer class]]) {
    [self removeGestureRecognizer:recognizer];
}
```

Hope this helps.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Replace `UIGestureRecognizer` with `UISwipeGestureRecognizer` if that's what you want to remove.

```
extension SKView {
    func removeAllGestureRecognizers() {
        if let objects = gestureRecognizers {
            for object in objects {
                if let gestureRecognizer = object as? UIGestureRecognizer {
                    removeGestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```